# How to understand this Linux sort output

Tags: linux

I ran Linux sort on one txt file and got the output below:

```
root@nxxx:~# cat b.txt
(52819531,3245)
(528,216)
(52819532,32680)
(52821791,3072)
(52821795,30713)
root@nxxx:~# sort -k1 -t, b.txt
(52819531,3245)
(52819532,32680)
(528,216)
(52821791,3072)
(52821795,30713)
```

I suppose it should be like:

```
(528,216)
(52819531,3245)
(52819532,32680)
(52821791,3072)
(52821795,30713)
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that produces the example output you've provided, or are you really looking for an explanation as to why `sort` did what it did?

Answer (score 1):

Try add -V sort it naturally...

```
(528,216)
(52819531,3245)
(52819532,32680)
(52821791,3072)
(52821795,30713)
```